# Best way to test conditions on a dynamic list of items?

Tags: javascript, loops, multiple-conditions

First off, sorry if the title is not 100% accurate.

I have a problem.

I have a dynamic list of items in List A, the number of items can be anywhere between 1-50:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

I need a function that loops through these items checking if a condition is true to each of these items like so:

```
if(item1 && condition) continue
```

What is the best way to go about creating this function/algorithm? As the list is not static I cannot hardcode the conditions like so:

```
if(item1 && condition) continue
if(item2 && condition) continue
if(item3 && condition) continue
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: I want the function to return true if at least one of the conditions is true.

Comment: The pseudo code the OP does present with the `continue` clause (which indicates the usage of `every`) gets entirely contradicted by the OP's last sentence ... *"I want the function to return true if at least one of the conditions is true"* ... (which indicates the usage of `some`).

Comment: Yes that's right, what I meant by continue was if any of those conditions are met then continue else stop. That's why there's 3 continues and not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

```
let result = arr.some(element => predicate(element));
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked the MDN for every, but the problem is, every() checks if all conditions are true, I want it to return true even if one of the array items is true?

Comment: @codingexplorer Then use `Array#some`.

Comment: @codingexplorer Glad to help.